# How to fix "invalid://" message while trying to get urser's info on Linkedin API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, request, linkedin-api

I'm working on a project that requires some user's Linkedin profile info. On the code below I try to get the info I need but an error is showed in the console:

> in.js:7 jSecure Error: URL should be absolute with allowed schemas,
>   relative, a hash fragment or query string.
>   TODO?client_id='HmZRETtXAzXwT6bR';&type=user-agent in.js:7  jSecure
>   Error: URL should be absolute with allowed schemas, relative, a hash
>   fragment or query string.
>   invalid://?scope=r_basicprofile%2Cr_emailaddress&xdOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww…5d-4de8-8f3d-5b9a39d4d639&xd_origin_host=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domadigital.com
>   in.js:7  jSecure Error: URL should be absolute with allowed schemas,
>   relative, a hash fragment or query string.
>   TODO?client_id='HmZRETtXAzXwT6bR';&type=user-agent

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: <my_api_secret_key>;
    </script>

    <script>
        var liLogin = function () { // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
            IN.UI.Authorize().params({ "scope": ["r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress"] }).place();
            IN.Event.on(IN, 'auth', getProfileData);
        }

        var getProfileData = function () { // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
            IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id,firstName,lastName,email-address,picture-urls::(original),public-profile-url,location:(name)").result(function (me) {
                var profile = me.values[0];
                var id = profile.id;
                var firstName = profile.firstName;
                var lastName = profile.lastName;
                var emailAddress = profile.emailAddress;
                var pictureUrl = profile.pictureUrls.values[0];
                var profileUrl = profile.publicProfileUrl;
                var country = profile.location.name;

                console.log(profile);
                console.log(id);
                console.log(firstName);
                console.log(lastName);
                console.log(emailAddress);
                console.log(pictureUrl);
                console.log(profileUrl);
                console.log(country);
            });
        }

        $("#btn-linkedin").click(function() {
            liLogin();
        });
    </script>
```

Obs. I am making these requests on a valid https domain, some requests are being made to facebook and google api that are working pretty fine.